# Python interning

Tags: python, cpython

Let's assume we have file foo.py

```py
a = 257
b = 257
print(a is b)
```

When I launch it from the terminal (`python3 ./foo.py`) the output is True:

```bash
(.venv) user@group:~/development/playground$ python3 ./foo.py 
True
```

When I launch it directly using python interpreter the output is False (as descibed in every article about interning)

```bash
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> print(a is b)
False
```

Could you explain why it works like this?
Python version:
Python 3.10.12

I'm expecting the explanation how it works and why I see sth like this

Comment: "Could you explain why it works like this?" The "why" is because "python internal implementation details make the first case intern but not the second, and this doesn't matter because you should never rely on these implementation details". The detail here, is that immutable literals in the same code block are re-used. A REPL evaluates each expression as a seperate code block.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you very much for the explanation